# Cocos2d-x v3 iOS app not registering first x touch events

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have a really weird issue with cocos2d-x v3, the first 15 touches or so are not registered on my iOS device (tried iPad 2 and iPad air). As soon as a touch is finally registered, everything works fine (aka all touches after that trigger the onTouch functions).

The touch events work perfectly fine in the simulator.
Also, the same code works perfectly fin in my Windows and Android builds.

Has anyone had this happen, or maybe know what could be causing it?

I'm using the listener, and I debugged up to the spot where touchesBegan forwards the input events to the listener, but even there the events don't come in until after the 15th tap or so.

It's really weird... And I figured I'd give it a shot here, as someone might have encountered this as well, before I start stripping code to as clean as possible, and then try to work my way back from there...

Kind regards,
Michaël

EDIT: As requested, here is some code. The desired behaviour is that it works in iOS devices like it should: First touch triggers the onTouchBegan.

I didn't add it as it didn't think it would matter, since the code works fine for Android.
But I appreciate that you'd like to see it, just in case I might have missed something

GameLayer is a Cocos2d::Layer.

```
void GameLayer::onEnter()
{
    cocos2d::CCLayer::onEnter();

    // Register Touch Event
    auto pEventDispatcher = cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher();
    if (pEventDispatcher)
    {
        // Touch listener
        auto pTouchListener = cocos2d::EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
        if (pTouchListener)
        {
            pTouchListener->setSwallowTouches( true );
            pTouchListener->onTouchBegan        = CC_CALLBACK_2( GameLayer::onTouchBegan, this );
            pTouchListener->onTouchMoved        = CC_CALLBACK_2( GameLayer::onTouchMoved, this );
            pTouchListener->onTouchEnded        = CC_CALLBACK_2( GameLayer::onTouchEnded, this );
            pTouchListener->onTouchCancelled    = CC_CALLBACK_2( GameLayer::onTouchCancelled, this );
            pEventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority( pTouchListener, this );
        }
    }
}


bool GameLayer::onTouchBegan( cocos2d::Touch* pTouch, cocos2d::Event* /*pEvent*/ )
{
    // Breakpoint here triggers fine on first touch for Android/Windows/iOS Simulator,
    // but not on iOS device (iPad/iPhone)
    bool breakHere = true;
    <<snip actual code>>
}
```

EDIT:
The problem was an std::ofstream trying to open() on the iOS device (most likely in a folder it didn't have access to).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: I don't have this issue at all. Can you show some code about what is working and what you think isn't so we can help?

Comment: I added the requested info... I don't mind posting all the code, but I thought that would make a huge post, and I'd get flamed :)  
  
 I was just checking if someone had encountered similar behaviour, as it's very specific (first ## touches don't register on iOS device, but as soon as one does register, everything works fine afterwards).  
  
 If noone has seen this before, I will create a small demo project and start working from there... Right now I would have to post my whole engine code, and that would be a bit TMI.

Comment: What version of cocos2d-x you use?

Comment: Wez: 3.1.1 for Android, 3.0 for iOS.

Comment: I think what I'll try, is createw a whole new xcode project, and start from scratch there. Maybe there is something wrong there, since the problem doesn't seem to have happened to anyone else.  Once I figure it out, I'll let you guys know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed.

The problem was seemingly totally unrelated, I was trying to open an std::ofstream file (my log file), most likely in a folder it didn't have (any and/or write) access to.
Which is not required, nor wanted on the iOS device.

Once I added IOS to the exclusion list (just like Android and some more targets) everything started to work perfect.

I do not know what goes wrong exactly, and why it does start working after a few touch inputs, but I'm guess it was waiting or retrying something in the background.

I found the issue while debugging another one :)
Hopefully this helps anyone else who might stumble onto the same or a related issue.

Kind regards,
Michaël

Answer (score 0):

I have lots of layers in my game and I don't do it like you do. In your code the need to get the EventDispatcher locally and create the touch listener like how you are seems odd to me. I've never seen it down that way in so many steps.

I do:

```
auto listener = cocos2d::EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
listener->setSwallowTouches(true);

listener->onTouchBegan = [&](cocos2d::Touch* touch, cocos2d::Event* event)
{
    return true;
};

listener->onTouchEnded = [=](cocos2d::Touch* touch, cocos2d::Event* event)
{
    // ... do something

};

cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWithFixedPriority(listener, 31);
```

Comment: That is because Cocos2d-x is just a target for my engine. I also have native Direct X support, Flash support and support for specific SDKs needed for embedded systems. I write the actual game code once, and then I can release to everything supported. Plus if something new comes out, I just add a target, and the game works on that to.

Comment: ok, you might do that but you can't not do what cocos2d-x needs because you support other game engine targets. I support more too and I don't have your issues. I'd just step through what you are doing and validate it then.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is something weird going on, that's why I'll restart with a whole clean project. I'm doing everything cocos2d-x needs, that's why it works fine :)  There is just this weird issue while running on actual iOS devices, and I did debug it back down to the highest level of readable code in the cocos code, and there to it only triggered after like 15/20 presses.  I will keep you guys posted on my findings...

Comment: For the record, the same engine ran fine on cocos2d v1, but I upgraded to cocos2d-x v3, so that I wouldn't have to support 2 different versions of cocos (3 actually, counting Windows RT).